# scrollTop offset() not animating/working correctly with divs inside of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, offset

Im trying to use simple jquery offset() and animate to make my div scroll to the desired div when the user clicks on a link.

Basically, when the user clicks blog it will go to test1
user clicks Contact it will move to test2
user clicks Work it will move to test3.

I implemented some code I had used in a previous project (it had worked before) but the scrolls are not working correctly this time and I really don't know the reason why. I tried searching for a solution but web development has been an on and off thing for me and I don't understand some of the explanations :/ Any help would be appreciated.

EditOne: had to update the html, still not working.

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css"  />


<title>Bryan the Lion</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function go_One(){
    var divPosition = $('.test1').offset();
    $('#main_wrapper #main').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "fast");
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function go_Two(){
    var divPosition = $('.test2').offset();
    $('#main_wrapper #main').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "fast");
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function go_Three(){
    var divPosition = $('.test3').offset();
    $('#main_wrapper #main').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "fast");
    }
    </script>
    <div id = "header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id = "main_box">
        <div id = "designHex">

        </div>
        <div id ="nav">
            <ul>
            <li id = "Blog"><a href="#" onclick= "go_One()"></a></li>
            <li id = "Contact"><a href="#"onclick= "go_Two()"></a></li>
            <li id = "Work"><a href="#" onclick= "go_Three()"></a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id = "main_wrapper">
            <div id ="main">
                <div class = "test1">
                    <p>some div</p>
                </div>
                <div class = "test2" >
                    <p>some div2</p>
                </div>  
                <div class = "test3" >
                    <p>some div3</p>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

The CSS: Of most importance here I think are main_wrapper, main, and test(1)(2)(3)

```
body{
height: 100% ;
background: url(images/gplaypattern.png); 
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "AlexBrush";
    src: url(fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}
#header{
height: 100px ;
margin-bottom: 20px ;
}
#main_box{   
margin: 0 auto ;
width: 80% ;
height: 52  0px ;

}
#main_wrapper{
margin-left: 45% ;      
width: 67%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#main_wrapper #main{
   width: 103%;
    height: 500px ;
    overflow-y:scroll; 
}
.test1{
height: 500px ;
background: yellow;
}
.test2{
height: 500px ;
background: blue;
}
.test3{
height: 500px ;
background: gray;
}
#nav{
float: left;
width: 275px ;
height: 450px ;
margin-left: 3% ;
}
#nav ul li a{
display: block;
width: 100% ;
height: 150px ;
}
#nav ul li a:hover{
cursor: pointer;
}
#nav #Blog{
background: url(images/Blog.png);
}
#nav #Blog:hover{
background: url(images/Blog_hover.png);
}
#nav #Contact{
background: url(images/Contact.png);
}
#nav #Contact:hover{
background: url(images/Contact_hover.png);
}
#nav #Work{
background: url(images/Work.png);
}
#nav #Work:hover{
background: url(images/Work_hover.png);
}
#designHex{
background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
height: 150px ;
width: 150px ;
position: absolute;
top: 50px ;
left: 5% ;
}
```

Comment: Does the console return any error when you load the page / click on the link ? By the way, your code contains a lot of errors.

Comment: It says uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: So correct your code, and that will be fine :)

Comment: actually, nvm, I had changed something in the index.php. But I reverted it and the console is not showing any errors. srry. but its not working

Comment: Would you be so kind as to point the errors to me? I mean, there is a reason I am posting this on stack overflow, if I knew how to correct the errors myself I would have done it.

Comment: FYI, you don't need different script blocks for different functions… You can put them all in a single one and you're code will be more readable… (unless there is some particular reason which i can't think of in this case)

Comment: Can you make a live example to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: JSFiddle in answer below. The problem was forgetting the parent offset as it is also relative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to take into account the scrollTop AND offset of the parent div:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Uafxz/2/

```
function scrollTo(selector) {
    var offset = $(selector).offset();
    var $main = $('#main');
    $main.animate({
        scrollTop: offset.top - ($main.offset().top - $main.scrollTop())
    }, "fast");
}
```

I changed your code to use a single function (passing the target selector). I removed the second id selector as ids are unique and id lookup is the fastest type of lookup anyway (no point slowing it down with a second search).

Note: I had to hide your `designHex` element for the JSFiddle as it overlapped the first link.

Comment: thank you so much, I appreciate you taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

**You actually don't target the good element** to animate scrollTop :

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "fast"); // instead of #main_wrapper #main
```

*And as said in comment, your code contains a lot of errors or non-standard notation. For example, you use 3 script tag and 3 function that do the same job. That could be done with only one.*

Comment: The scrolling *is* apparently meant to apply to the div with the 3 divs. The whole page is not the target of his scrolling.

Comment: Yea, I tried this code and it didn't work. 
As true blue said, there is nothing wrong with the scrolling itself, just that it behaves erratically. Well, he didn't say that but he's right about the targeted element.

Comment: Ok, I thought you tried to make the window scroll to the targeted element.